# C++ Stack data structure to push and pop string and float data types

Tags: c++

I have written the below C++ code to implement a stack which can push and pop integer, float and strings. It is working fine for only some value. Also, when i push something for the first time and display it, the first element always has garbage values following it. Also, i am getting the following error: Suppose i first push Hello and display it, the previously mentioned problem occurs. Now, if i push 141 and display, i see garbage value next to 141. Same thing for any floating point value. However, if i push 1 and display, i see no garbage values next to 1. I get 1 only just like i want it. How can i fix all these problems? Thanks.

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

class stack {

private:
    char stk[10][10];
    int top;

public:

    stack()
    {
        top=-1;
    }

    void push(char x[])
    {
        int count=0,i=0,n;
        n=strlen(x);
        if(top>9)
        {cout << "Stack overflow";
        return;}
        else
        {
            top++;
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {if(x[i]=='\0')
            {count=i;
            break;}
            else
            stk[top][i]=x[i];}
            return;
            for(i=count;i<n;i++)
            stk[top][i]='\0';
        }

    }

    void pop()
    {
        int i;
        if(top==-1)
        {
            cout <<"Stack underflow";
            return;
        }
        else
        cout << stk[top--];
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        stk[top+1][i]='\0';
    }

    void display()
    {
        if(top==-1)
        {
            cout << "Stack empty";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=top;i>-1;i--)
            {cout << stk[i] << endl;}
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    char ch[10];
    int x;
    stack st;
    while(1)
    {
        cout <<"\n1.push 2.pop 3.display 4.exit\nEnter your choice ";
        cin >>x;
        switch(x)
        {
            case 1: cout <<"Enter element ";
                    cin>>ch;
                    st.push(ch);
                    break;
            case 2: st.pop(); break;
            case 3: st.display(); break;
            case 4: exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want it to store those three separate types, use a variant. It's much cleaner.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? This doesn't even compile on gcc. Your main function is missing a type and you never declared `count` in your push function...

Comment: Dev C++. Sorry about the count thing and the main function type. I edited the post. Please check now.

Comment: Don't hardcode the size as 10. Use a constant or variable.

Comment: Sorry for the noobness but how can i do that?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::string`s? If you can use `std::string`s, use `std::string`s. And a `std::vector` to hold the data

Answer (score 2):

The garbage problem is because you aren't null terminating your strings when you copy them to the stack. You've tried to null terminate them, but you've put `return` before your null terminating code, so it never executes.

There are so many ways to make this code better and simpler, but I'll mention just one, use `strcpy` to copy a string (and also don't use `return` when you don't have to).

```
void push(char x[])
{
    if (top >= 9)
    {
        cout << "Stack overflow";
    }
    else
    {
        top++;
        strcpy(stk[i], x);
    }
}
```

And as is pointed out in the comments below your check for stack overflow is incorrect. I've fixed that too.